# как сделать ссылки на странице поисковика

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста как сделать такие ссылочки в поисковике:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти штуки называются Site Links. Не существует определенного способа добавления их в поисковую выдачу. Для того чтобы они появились, Ваш сайт должен иметь высокий рейтинг. Кроме того, Гугл сам решает какие ссылки достаточно полезны юзеру чтобы их показывать (на основании различных показателей: качество структуры сайта, количество посещений страницы и т.д.).

Некоторую информацию можно почерпнуть тут:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitelink